# yii datepiker not working

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2

I am using "dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker", install it via composer everything is right. But after I uploaded it on the server, it stoped to work, not showing calendar when click.

Here I am using it with model.

```
   <?=   $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(
                  DatePicker::className(), [
                      'language' => 'ru',
                      'inline' => false,
                      'clientOptions' => [
                          'autoClose' => true,
                          'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                      ]
                  ]); ?>
```

However it didn't work without model. Tried to add all scripts, but still no result.

```
 <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\grid\GridView;
    use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $searchModel app\models\DateSearch */
    /* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

    $this->title = 'Dates';
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <?= DatePicker::widget([
            'name' => 'Test',
              'inline' => false,
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                ]
        ]);?>
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/libs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/libs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Moreover there is no errors in console.

Comment: i've similiar problem when using other widget, the source of the problem is that i load two jquery script, one in my layout and one is loaded by the widget. try to check it, maybe it's the same thing with your problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, adding script is not necessary. So, first remove it.

Secondly, You showed 2 examples which are totally different apart.

**1)**

```
<?=   $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
           .
           .          
]); ?>
```

**2)**

```
<?= DatePicker::widget([
           .
           . 
]);?>
```

In which 1st one is correct and it should work. But, as you showed us complete code in the 2nd example, I saw calling datepicker in different way. No FORM, no FIELD. Use 1st example in 2nd one. And, see whether it's working or not.

Comment: so, actually I am using first one but it not working. Main idea is that, at localhost everything is good, but after uploading it is not showing calendar and not clickable.